# Trouble with CellList empty widget and AsyncDataProvider

Tags: java, gwt, celllist

I have a CellList that I'm populating with an `AsyncDataProvider`:

```
  @UiField(provided = true)
  CellList<PlayerDataEntity> friendCellList;


  @Inject
  FriendListViewImpl(FriendListController controller) {
    friendCellList = new CellList<PlayerDataEntity>(new PlayerCell());

    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));

    // if we don't set the row data to empty before trying to get the real data,
    // the empty list widget will never appear. But if we do set this, 
    // then the real data won't show up. 
    friendCellList.setRowData(Lists.<PlayerDataEntity>newArrayList());

      new AsyncDataProvider<PlayerDataEntity>() {
        @Override
        protected void onRangeChanged(final HasData<PlayerDataEntity> display) {
          rpcService.getPlayers(new AsyncCallback<List<PlayerDataEntity>>() {
              @Override
              public void onSuccess(List<PlayerDataEntity> result) {
                 display.setRowData(0, result);
              }
            });
      }
    }.addDataDisplay(friendCellList);

    friendCellList.setEmptyListWidget(new Label("No friends found"));
  }
```

If I don't initially set the row data to an empty list, then the empty list widget won't show up if the RPC service returns an empty list. However, if I do initially set the row data to the an empty list, and the RPC returns a non-empty list, that data won't show up in the widget.

I must be misunderstanding some aspect of the `CellList`'s API. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know, that the total list (not just the list in the range) is empty, then you can set `display.setRowCount(0)`, so the CellList will display "No friends found".

If your service always returns the entire list, this can be done easily like

```
public void onSuccess(List<PlayerDataEntity> result) {
  display.setRowCount(result.size());
  display.setRowData(0, result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to the method:

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(List<PlayerDataEntity> result) {
   display.setRowData(0, result);
   ((CellList<PlayerDataEntity>) display).redraw();
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but it doesn't seem to work. The unwanted behavior described in the OP persists.