# How can I nudge a GWT CellList populated with AsyncDataProvider to refresh its content?

Tags: gwt

I've setup a CellList using an AsyncDataProvider that calls a server with a search string.

When my user enters a new search string I want CellList to refresh.

How can I tell my CellList to refresh? Do I call removeDataDisplay() and then addDataDisplay?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566483/trouble-with-celllist-empty-widget-and-asyncdataprovider

Comment: Also search across stackoverflow gwt tag with AsyncDataProvider and [gwt]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try.

```
cellList.setVisibleRangeAndClearData(cellList.getVisibleRange(), true);
```

[Reload celltable issue](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.org.google.gwt/52306)

Answer (score 4):

[`setVisibleRangeAndClearData`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/AbstractHasData.html#setVisibleRangeAndClearData%28com.google.gwt.view.client.Range,%20boolean%29) maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `cellList.setVisibleRangeAndClearData( range, true)` API to trigger the onRangeChange method of the AsyncDataProvider.

Since you are using Cell list, the above mentioned `call should happen when the user scrolls to the end of the currently visible list`. And the Range should be -

```
private Range range = new Range( cellList.getVisibleRange().getStart() + cellList.getVisibleRange().getLength(), cellList.getVisibleRange().getLength() );

cellList.setVisibleRangeAndClearData( range, true);
```